# Rspec failing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am receiving the following errors for my Rspec test in rails

```
1) MoviesController searching for similar movies should find the similar movies by director
     Failure/Error: get :similar, {:id => "1"}
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Movie with id=1
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:63:in `similar'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) MoviesController searching for similar movies should select the Similiar Movies template for rendering
     Failure/Error: get :similar, {:id => "1"}
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Movie with id=1
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:63:in `similar'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) MoviesController searching for similar movies it should make the results available to the template
     Failure/Error: get :similar, {:id => "1"}
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Movie with id=1
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:63:in `similar'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

And this is my controller method that is causing it to fail:

```
def similar
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:id])
  @movies = Movie.find_all_by_director(Movie.find_by_id(params[:id])[:director])
  if @movies.count <= 1
    redirect_to movies_path
    flash[:notice] = "'#{@movie.title}' has no director info"
end
```

I can't understand why this test keeps failing with the same error. Any help would be much appreciated

Below are the tests

```
describe MoviesController do
  describe 'searching for similar movies' do
    before :each do 
      @fake_movies = [mock('Movie'), mock('Movie')]
      @fake_movie = FactoryGirl.build(:movie, :id => "1", :title => "Star Wars", :director => "George Lucas") 
end
it 'should follow the route to the similar movies by director page' do
  assert_routing('movies/1/similar', {:controller => 'movies', :action => 'similar', :id => '1'}) 
end

it 'should find the similar movies by director' do
  Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
  Movie.should_receive(:find_all_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
  get :similar, {:id => "1"}
end

it 'should select the Similiar Movies template for rendering' do
  Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
  Movie.should_receive(:find_all_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
  get :similar, {:id => "1"}
  response.should render_template('similar')
end

it 'it should make the results available to the template' do
  Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
  Movie.should_receive(:find_all_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
  get :similar, {:id => "1"}
  assigns(:movies).should == @fake_results
end
end
end
```

FactoryGirl is setup as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :movie do
    title 'Star Wars' 
    director 'George Lucas'
  end
end
```

Comment: It's not finding your movie when you do `Movie.find(params[:id])`. Did you set up a movie object in your Rspec test? Are you certain it has ID=1? It most likely will not.

Comment: Can you show the test that's failing?

Comment: Note that the test database is used, not the development database.

You probably haven't set up any test movies, might I suggest FactoryGirl?

Comment: Hi Nils, I edited it to show the FactoryGirl setup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spec calls `Factory.build`. That does not persist the object to the database. You'll want to use `Factory.create` to allow `Movie.find` to work.

Comment: Yep, that's your problem right there.

Personally, I try to stay away from IDs in tests if possible, and would change a line like `get :similar, {:id => "1"}` to `get :similar, {:id => @fake_movie.id}`, but either way using create instead of build is the way to go.

Comment: That did the trick! And @NilsLandt thank you for the insight as well